# How to progressively decrease a value from a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as listed below:

```
[1] df
    name   value
     a      116
     b      116
     c      116
     d      225
     e      225
     f      225
     g      225
```

Now I want the df to become

```
    name   value
     a      116
     b      115
     c      114
     d      225
     e      224
     f      223
     g      222
```

That is, wherever original df had same (fixed) values in a column in consecutive rows, it should decrease down progressively by 1.  So, values in value column for names a,b,c go from 116 to 114. And for d,e,f,g go from 225 to 222.

Kindly advice.

Comment: What if they have the same value but are not consecutive ? e.g. if there were one more row `h` with value `116`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count consecutive values and subtract from column `value`:

```
#consecutive rows to Series g
g = df['value'].ne(df['value'].shift()).cumsum()
df['value'] = df['value'] - df.groupby(g).cumcount()
print (df)
  name  value
0    a    116
1    b    115
2    c    114
3    d    225
4    e    224
5    f    223
6    g    222
```

Comment: Always no reason , I really tired of downvote without reason : -(

Answer (score 3):

If consecutive values are unique, you can `transform`

```
df.groupby('value').value.transform(lambda k: k - k.reset_index().index)

0    116
1    115
2    114
3    225
4    224
5    223
6    222
```

Comment: This won't work if you have non consecutive blocks of the same value (as in your comment, the last 116 would also get subtracted). Unless that's what OP wanted, which is possible (it's a bit unclear)...

Answer (score 3):

Using `cumcount`

```
df.value-=df.groupby('value').cumcount()
df
Out[215]: 
  name  value
0    a    116
1    b    115
2    c    114
3    d    225
4    e    224
5    f    223
6    g    222
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a cleaner way to do this, but you can get your desired outcome like this:

```
df['value'] = (df.assign(x = df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
               .groupby('x')
               .value
               .transform(lambda y: y - y.reset_index().index))
>>> df
  name  value
0    a    116
1    b    115
2    c    114
3    d    225
4    e    224
5    f    223
6    g    222
```

Essentially, this creates a column which flags consecutive blocks of equal numbers (which I called `x`), groupby that column, and then subtract by the result of `reset_index`, which is just a `range` object, the length of each consecutive group (i.e. subtract `0` from the first, `1` from the second, and so on...)

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to sort your dataframe value column then you can just use a simple for loop for decreasing values.

```
dataframe = dataframe.sort_values('value')                  #sort column 'value' 
j=0
for i in range(len(dataframe.index)-1):
    if(dataframe.iloc[i, 1] == dataframe.iloc[i+1,1]):            #if ith row value is equal to i+1th row value
        dataframe.iloc[i,1] = dataframe.iloc[i,1] - j             #then decrease 
        j = j + 1

    elif(dataframe.iloc[i, 1] != dataframe.iloc[i+1,1]):          # if not then decrease ith row value and again start with
        dataframe.iloc[i,1] = dataframe.iloc[i,1] - j             # j=0
        j=0

#print(j)                                                          
#print(i)
if(dataframe.iloc[i+1,1] == dataframe.iloc[i-j+1,1]):           # for last row check whether it is repeatation of original value
    dataframe.iloc[i+1,1] = dataframe.iloc[i+1,1] - j           # or not, if it is then decrease it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.assign(col2=1)
    return dd.assign(value=dd1.col2.cumsum().mul(-1).add(1).add(dd1['value']))

col1=df1['value'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df1.groupby(col1).apply(function1)
```

out：

```
 name  value
0    a    116
1    b    115
2    c    114
3    d    225
4    e    224
5    f    223
6    g    222
```